# What chemical regularly transported by road in the UK would cause serious injury/loss of life if it escaped in a road accident?

Tags: safety, chemistry-in-fiction

I'm writing a story where a serious multi-vehicle pileup happens in the winter during foggy weather. I need the fallout from this to include the escape of a substance that will cause significant injury/loss of life to those immediately involved in the accident.

What chemical can I use that is regularly transported by road in the UK that could cause this to happen?

Comment: Liquified Petroleum Gas (Flo Gas or Calor) - if it spilled and ignited

Comment: Chlorine, particularly in still, foggy weather (the main contributing factor to the only fatalities in large bulk transport of chlorine in the US that I know of).

Comment: Likely one of your choice https://www.gov.uk/guidance/moving-dangerous-goods

Comment: Liquid sodium? I used to work near a plant (now closed) where 40 Ton tankers of liquid sodium were a key feedstock. And this was considered safer than manual loading of sodium ingots into the plant.

Comment: Liquid nitrogen/carbon dioxide could asphyxiate many nearby.

Comment: A leaking lorry valve poured a large amount of solvent (acetone, perhaps) along a major Massachusetts highway, dissolving the asphalt of a large section. The fumes also nauseated and intoxicated drivers going over that section. Luckily, it did not catch fire, but it took some time to dig up the roadbed and remetal it.

Answer (score 0):

Organophosphates in general would be a great idea as you can go from potent insecticides to chemical warfare as it fits the drama of your story.